# CSE input box text/value

Tags: jquery, google-custom-search

I have googled this and checked here but couldnt find  solution for me. So here's the question:

I want to change the google custom search box input default text 
(since i removed the branding image because i use a bg color on the input and it looks so bad then)
to show "Google search..." to comply with the tos and show users what the search is..

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('input.gsc-input').val('Google search..');
});
```

but that isn't working. Anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: can you try  $(document).load instead of  $(document).ready ?

Answer (score 1):

Find out the id of the text box.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('gsc-i-id1').value='Google search..';
});
```

best of luck.